# Android - Copy build output to another folder with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to build my React Native Android app on Visual Studio App Center and I get this error:

```
Task         : Shell script
Description  : Run a shell script using Bash
Version      : 2.165.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/shell-script
==============================================================================
[command]/bin/bash /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/scripts/android-postprocess.sh /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/mobile/android/app/app/build/outputs/apk
Removing all ABI or density dependent APKs…
find: /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/mobile/android/app/app/build/outputs/apk: No such file or directory
find: /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/mobile/android/app/app/build/outputs/apk: No such file or directory
find: /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/mobile/android/app/app/build/outputs/apk: No such file or directory
Found        0 APK file(s)
Found        0 unaligned APK file(s)
find: /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/mobile/android/app/app/build/outputs/apk: No such file or directory
/Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/scripts/android-postprocess.sh: line 36: pushd: /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/mobile/android/app/app/build/outputs/apk/..: No such file or directory
/Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/scripts/android-postprocess.sh: line 43: popd: directory stack empty

##[error]The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
##[error]Bash failed with error: The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
##[section]Finishing: Android Postprocess
##[section]Starting: Post Build Script
```

It's incorrectly looking for my APK in the app/app/build/... instead of app/build/...So I want to copy the files to app/app/build/.. so it finds them there.

I can't copy the files with a post-build script because it runs after the script that throws the error.

Is it possible to somehow achieve copying with Gradle? Or maybe have multiple build paths? Or some other solution?

Comment: `android-postprocess.sh` is being passed the wrong path, to begin with... and this question has nothing to do with Gradle.

Comment: Where would I configure that?

Comment: How shall I know? you've provided no code; just search for it. That path might have been glued together from 2-3 parts; and it might even run on actual Linux.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I had `gradlew`, `gradlew.bat` and `gradle` folder in my `app`module folder. I must have mistakenly opened the app folder alone in Android Studio and synced the project. 
 
I solved it by creating a fresh React Native project.